# Can someone explain how a to write, then display a vector, reverse it, and display the reversed vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm more so asking how the code would work, not for the actual code.  I just need help understanding it.  Any help would be appreciated:)
PS: I'm a C++ noob

Comment: You have to learn how to use `iterator` also you can look here for reverse order [`rbegin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/rbegin/?kw=vector%3A%3Arbegin)

Answer (score 2):

Rough outline

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<cstdio>

// some code goes here
std::vector<std::string> myVectorOfStrings;
// some code goes here
myVectorOfStrings.push_back(someStringValue);  // this might be in a loop
// some code goes here
for( std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator itr = myVectorOfStrings.begin();
     itr != myVectorOfStrings.end();
     itr++ )
{
    cout << *itr << endl; // obviously you might want to be neater here
}
```

...and so on.  Try it yourself (including figuring out the reverse part by yourself), post the code you have, and what problems you're having.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector>       

int main () {
  std::vector<int> myvector;

  // set some values: write in a vector
  for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) myvector.push_back(i);   // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

  // print the values of the vector
  for (int i=0; i<myvector.size(); i++) cout<<myvector[i]<<" ";

  // reverse the vector
  std::reverse(myvector.begin(),myvector.end());    // 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

  // print out content:
  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds suspiciously like homework.  Additionally, there are several ways to do this.  You said you don't want the actual code, so here goes:

#### How to write [a vector]

I assume this means "create a vector and put things in it."  The thing is, I have no idea what you want to put in it.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### then display a vector

There are several ways to do this.  The coolest I know is to use [`ostream_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ostream_iterator/).  But if this is for a class, the teacher will probably be a little surprised to see that.

#### reverse [the vector]

There is a [`std::reverse`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/).  If that's not acceptable, you can simply [swap the first element with the last element, the second element with the next to last element, etc](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf) (PDF, pg. 143).  Be careful to stop when you've swapped the first half of the vector with the last half.  If you keep going, you'll reverse the vector **again**, which will leave you with what you started with.

#### and display the reversed vector?

This is nothing more than redoing the code to display the vector in the first place.